# How can I query using .whereField for a member of an Array?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to query an Array of user IDs, which are held in an Array in my Firestore database. This is working, and it is successfully displaying the UIDs in my console. I want to, then, find when field "uid" is equal to a member of the array. This is where it stops working. I cannot seem to be able to actually match the "uid" with a member of the followedUID Array.

I detail my code below. Any help would be greatly appreciated:

```
 func getFollowingPosts() {
                db.collection("iAmFollowing").document(currentUserID!).getDocument { (document, error) in
                if error != nil {
                    print("ERROR")
                } else {
                    if let document = document {
                        let followedUID = document["uid"] as? Array ?? [""]
                        print("followed UID is \(followedUID)")
                        
                        
                        let searchedInfo = self.db.collection("posts").whereField("uid", isEqualTo: followedUID)
                        

                       let refinedInfo = searchedInfo.order(by: "Alpha", descending: true)
                       refinedInfo.getDocuments { (documents, error) in
                                guard let documents = documents else {
                                    print("NO DOCUMENTS")
                                   return
                                }
                                for documents in documents.documents {
                                let title = documents.get("Title") as! String
                                let content = documents.get("Content") as! String
                                let username = documents.get("username") as! String
                                let postID = documents.get("postID")
                                let counter = documents.get("counter")
                                self.titleArray.append(title)
                                self.contentArray.append(content)
                                self.usernameArray.append(username)
                                self.postIDArray.append(postID as! Int)
                                self.effectsLabelArray.append(counter as! Int)
                                print(self.titleArray)
                                self.tableView.reloadData()
                                }
                            }
                            }
                       }
                    }
                    
                    }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query is asking for documents where the uid field is exactly equal to the given value:

```
db.collection("posts").whereField("uid", isEqualTo: followedUID)
```

If the uid field is an array, this query will never find anything, because an array is never equal to a string.

If you want to see if a field value is one of many values, use an ["in" query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#in_and_array-contains-any):

```
db.collection("posts").whereField("uid", in: followedUID)
```